# best and fastest way to store big amount of data in javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to store some data having 3 keys to uniquely determine each item.
For current example I use **i**, **j**, **z** as keys.

```js
console.time('global1');
var global1 = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
    for (var z = 0; z < 100; ++z) {
      global1[i] = global1[i] || {};
      global1[i][j] = global1[i][j] || {};
      global1[i][j][z] = global1[i][j][z] = { a: 123456789 };
    }
  }
}

console.timeEnd('global1');
```

```js
console.time('global2');
var global2 = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
    for (var z = 0; z < 100; ++z) {
      global2[[i,j,z]] = { a: 123456789 };
    }
  }
}

console.timeEnd('global2');
```

1. Why chrome do first example really much faster, what type of optimization is it ?
2. What best way to store that amount (or bigger) of data?

Comment: FYI, your second version doesn't have as many elements, and overwrites existing elements instead of adding new ones sometimes. `'' + 1 + 2 + 58 === '' + 12 + 5 + 8 ` for example. There are many others. You could put a separator between the numbers to fix that: `\`${i}_${j}_${z}\``

Comment: watch out, 'cause your second example overwrites your data. For example `i=12`, `j=34`, `z=5` results in the same key as `i=12`, `j=3`, `z=45` or `i=1`, `j=23`, `z=45`

Comment: Paul, it was separator at first there, have just removed it before posting, to make example easier to understand. my bad. fixed

Answer (score -1):

If you run different times both the snippets you can realize that the times are pretty similar, this because the computational complexity of an algorithm basically depend on the number of loop (that are the same).

If you need to store every single values I don't think there is other way to do that.

Comment: try chrome  for example (I have chrome 77). it's not similar at all
150-200ms for the first vs 1,5-2 seconds for the second.
(it's pretty same for firefox)

Comment: Sorry, when i ran the snippets I have the previous version of the code.